# Build referencing wrong database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In my settings, I am using a database called demo.accdb which is in a folder 'demo'. However, when I build my project, it is referencing demo.mdb which is an entirely different database in a different folder.

In my settings tab it is set as:

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\demo\demo.accdb`.

Where can I check why it is doing this?

Comment: You can temporarily messagebox the datasource upon app load to see if it's really referencing to the right database.

Comment: @chris how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Create a global variable to store your datasource string. Like Public databasepath as string="C:\demo\demo.accdb". Then you can do a msgbox(databasepath) upon form load. Check if your datasource is right or changing, if it's changing, some fishy code is executed before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Check **App.Config** File or Check The **Database Explorer** to Another Database Is Not Attached With Project.

or

You Can check  **Settings.Designer.vb** file in your solution

Comment: Pankeel. In my app.config and settings.designer they are pointing to demo.accdb. But in server explorer, they are pointing to demo.mdb. Can you help me to understand why this is happening. thanks

Comment: any other project use this database so server expoler save this setting so remove this database from server explorer and try to run your application

Comment: I have tried that pankeel, but it still builds using this db. Thanks

Comment: Go To  Project Folder open Settings.settings file in notepad & Check Database

Comment: Both the vb and other settings.settings file point to the correct db: <Value Profile="(Default)">Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\demo\demo.accdb</Value>

Comment: you can create new project add exiting all file run the applicaiton

Comment: When I go to build a project it fails with this: The ClickOnce manifests cannot be signed because they contain one or more references that are not hashed. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46455/discussion-between-pankeel-and-user1532468)